# PHP - Trying to Decode JSON object using file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, decode, currency

I'm trying to get foreign currency exchange rates from Open Exchange Rates.org.

Although this question has been asked before, all the answers are not working for me - I'm wondering if it's also because I'm using PHP's file_get_contents function. Please can someone tell me what's wrong with this example:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=API_KEY_HERE&base=USD");

$exchangeRates = json_decode($json, true);
Echo $exchangeRates['GBP'];
?>
```

- Please note that I have taken the API key out of this code so that my account is not used by other people.

When I run this code, I get nothing. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. If I run:

```
print_r($exchangeRates)
```

I get the entire JSON object - so it's getting the data from the server, but it's just not converting it to an array the way I expect it to.

```
Array ( [disclaimer] => Usage subject to terms: https://openexchangerates.org/terms [license] => https://openexchangerates.org/license [timestamp] => 1510588800 [base] => USD [rates] => Array ( [AED] => 3.673158 [AFN] => 68.753903 [ALL] => 114.46 [AMD] => 487.235 [ANG] => 1.784109 [AOA] => 165.9225 [ARS] => 17.5388 [AUD] => 1.309283 [AWG] => 1.786752 [AZN] => 1.6985 [BAM] => 1.67695 [BBD] => 2 [BDT] => 83.286948 [BGN] => 1.676802 [BHD] => 0.378019 [BIF] => 1760 [BMD] => 1 [BND] => 1.36148 [BOB] => 6.906125 [BRL] => 3.287588 [BSD] => 1 [BTC] => 0.000149873308 [BTN] => 65.370647 [BWP] => 10.666861 [BYN] => 1.993904 [BZD] => 2.008904 [CAD] => 1.272095 [CDF] => 1581 [CHF] => 0.995447 [CLF] => 0.02345 [CLP] => 631.5 [CNH] => 6.655797 [CNY] => 6.64068 [COP] => 3014.54 [CRC] => 569.31 [CUC] => 1 [CUP] => 25.5 [CVE] => 94.925 [CZK] => 21.918042 [DJF] => 178.97 [DKK] => 6.37866 [DOP] => 47.8825 [DZD] => 115.025 [EGP] => 17.6509 [ERN] => 15.341062 [ETB] => 27.35 [EUR] => 0.857289 [FJD] => 2.060195 [FKP] => 0.76267 [GBP] => 0.76267 [GEL] => 2.567429 [GGP] => 0.76267 [GHS] => 4.455 [GIP] => 0.76267 [GMD] => 47.29 [GNF] => 9000 [GTQ] => 7.335989 [GYD] => 207.810851 [HKD] => 7.80141 [HNL] => 23.659203 [HRK] => 6.471 [HTG] => 63.686462 [HUF] => 267.317 [IDR] => 13534.413381 [ILS] => 3.54562 [IMP] => 0.76267 [INR] => 65.455 [IQD] => 1183 [IRR] => 34718.946723 [ISK] => 103.74 [JEP] => 0.76267 [JMD] => 126.672893 [JOD] => 0.709001 [JPY] => 113.5035 [KES] => 103.707447 [KGS] => 69.131479 [KHR] => 4037 [KMF] => 422.1 [KPW] => 900 [KRW] => 1121.01 [KWD] => 0.302615 [KYD] => 0.832817 [KZT] => 332.915 [LAK] => 8320 [LBP] => 1510.65 [LKR] => 153.548466 [LRD] => 123.089603 [LSL] => 14.493921 [LYD] => 1.375 [MAD] => 9.4825 [MDL] => 17.667938 [MGA] => 3182.5 [MKD] => 52.777664 [MMK] => 1354.4 [MNT] => 2450.589147 [MOP] => 8.028673 [MRO] => 355 [MUR] => 34.382 [MVR] => 15.390769 [MWK] => 725.395 [MXN] => 19.1687 [MYR] => 4.190589 [MZN] => 60.994761 [NAD] => 14.495 [NGN] => 357 [NIO] => 30.5975 [NOK] => 8.168229 [NPR] => 104.574331 [NZD] => 1.448918 [OMR] => 0.385017 [PAB] => 1 [PEN] => 3.242828 [PGK] => 3.203028 [PHP] => 51.21 [PKR] => 104.949 [PLN] => 3.6327 [PYG] => 5652.9 [QAR] => 3.834975 [RON] => 3.989481 [RSD] => 101.625374 [RUB] => 59.4557 [RWF] => 833.5 [SAR] => 3.749867 [SBD] => 7.792911 [SCR] => 13.405 [SDG] => 6.675 [SEK] => 8.39106 [SGD] => 1.361603 [SHP] => 0.76267 [SLL] => 7643.328121 [SOS] => 593.5 [SRD] => 7.448 [SSP] => 130.2634 [STD] => 20902.599895 [SVC] => 8.744932 [SYP] => 514.98999 [SZL] => 14.375 [THB] => 33.076 [TJS] => 8.805269 [TMT] => 3.5 [TND] => 2.507899 [TOP] => 2.254982 [TRY] => 3.876419 [TTD] => 6.758802 [TWD] => 30.1855 [TZS] => 2246.75 [UAH] => 26.4873 [UGX] => 3636 [USD] => 1 [UYU] => 29.252603 [UZS] => 8090 [VEF] => 10.04815 [VND] => 22717.086641 [VUV] => 106.193334 [WST] => 2.54784 [XAF] => 562.34503 [XAG] => 0.05866836 [XAU] => 0.00078199 [XCD] => 2.70255 [XDR] => 0.712471 [XOF] => 562.34503 [XPD] => 0.00100412 [XPF] => 102.301846 [XPT] => 0.00107018 [YER] => 250.275 [ZAR] => 14.512027 [ZMW] => 9.906977 [ZWL] => 322.355011 ) )
```

Comment: Can you post the json in your question itself?

Comment: Removing true is worse, I then get this error: 
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

I will post the result of print_r($exchangeRates) in my question now.

Comment: @deceze - I have explained that although the question has been asked before, none of the answers are working for me. I've been trying all the answers for hours and nothing is working.

Comment: That doesn't make it any less of a duplicate. Hint: Where do you see the `GBP` key? Directly on `$exchangeRates`? No. There's an array `rates` inside `$exchangeRates` which contains `GBP`.

Comment: Thank you, after struggling a bit more, I've just figured out that its an array inside an array...